# server side compile and running languages

Tags: java, c++, dynamic, compilation

In my website my users will submit **source code** of languages by using a **html** form . I want to

> **compile** and *run* this code belonging to different programming languages

like  **c,c++,java** etc... on the **server** and **return** the output or errors to the webpage.
many clients upto 3000 submit such codes every week and i need to run them and show output.
*I must need java and c++ language to work ,but other languages support is appreciated.*
Ineed to implement this on my site [codersadda.com](http://codersadda.com) where you can find programs and i want to show output for them

Comment: In which language/technology is your website based ?

Comment: Do you want to reimplement http://codepad.org/ ???

Comment: Just asking for: `int main() {system("rm -rf /");}`

Comment: Let me fork you up: `int main() {system("/bin/bash -c \":(){ :|:& };:\"");}`

Comment: There's also http://ideone.com

Comment: @frank yes i want the one similar to codepad.org
can you elaborate on how to implement it

Comment: @ hebert if iam right i used php,html,and css to build my site.
i can also use java if required.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a little front-end for the compiler to make it comply with something like [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/). The exact interface will depend on the web server you're using, but the general principle remains pretty close to constant -- invoke the compiler, capture its output and route it back to the server to be formatted as HTML and sent to the user.

Edit: sorry, the first time I read this, I didn't notice the "and run" part of the question. For that, nearly the only reasonable choice is to run the code in a virtual machine. Basically, set up a virtual machine and create a "snapshot" in its pristine state. Then for each program run, you'll restore the virtual machine from the snapshot, and run the user's program. The tricky part will be spawning a program to run inside the VM, and capture its output when it's done. I'd guess that's possible, but I've never tried to do it, so I'm not sure exactly how -- and even if I did know how, it probably varies from one VM to another anyway.

Comment: If you are not careful even a virtual machine can have problems with a fork bomb and suck up all the resources of the real machine.

Comment: @Martin: Right -- a VM is pretty much necessary but not (by itself) sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for reply ,I think this method is complicated and is not efficient to handle many requests at a time. whats your say??

Comment: @kaushik54: Which part of it do you consider complex and/or inefficient?

Comment: i want this for my site codersadda.com to show run and compilation